# Flex 3: TextInput as ItemRenderer for CheckBox in ComboBox?

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, checkbox, itemrenderer, textinput

I need to create a Flex component similar to [ComboCheck](http://www.carballares.es/en/arcadio/?p=220) (by Arcadio Carballares).

What I need is a ComboBox with CheckBox and TextInput instead of Checkbox's label.
If CheckBox is selected the TextInput is enabled and editable, other way it's disabled.

Do you have an idea of the easiest way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an itemRenderer containing the check box and text input (and code to toggle the editable/enabled prop on the text input), and use that in your combo box as itemRenderer.

Comment: I just had a problem to write my ComboInput ItemRenderer as a pure AS Class. So I created MXML Component based on HBox and added CheckBox and TextInput in it (with a appropriate scripting ;-> )